# Split the list into multiple sublists heading by 1

Tags: python, list

Say I have a list like this:

```
lst = [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
```

I intended to split it into multiple sub-lists heading by 1:

```
new_lst = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]]
```

This is how I render it for now and it worked fine. Is there any simplier way to do it? Like itertools however I couldn't think of how at this moment.

```
one_list = []

for i, j in enumerate(lst):
    if j == 1:
        one_list.append(i)

new_list = []
for i in range(len(one_list)-1):
    head = one_list[i]
    tail = one_list[i+1]
    new_list.append(flag[head:tail])
```

Comment: It *is* possible to leverage `itertools.groupby` for this, but I don't think it's really any simpler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`more_itertools.split_before`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.split_before) will do exactly that

```
lst = list(more_itertools.split_before(lst, lambda x : x == 1))
# [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Right right. It is `more_itertools` I'm talking about. Tons of thanks